# Need to Download xml file from https url which needs password authentication

Tags: java

I am new to Java and currently struggling a bit.
    i am able to read the xml files and auhenication is also completed but I am not able to download it in client.
    For e.g URL looks like this:- "http://myworld.com/436789.xml".
     Destination:- "/infa_shared/cache".
     File Name to be saved at destination with name:- 436789.xml.
     Need to pass these three as variable.
    Below is the code:-

```
enter code here
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class MyMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        URL url;
        InputStream is = null;
        BufferedReader br;
        String line;

        // Install Authenticator
        MyAuthenticator.setPasswordAuthentication("User_name", "Password");
        Authenticator.setDefault(new MyAuthenticator());

        try {
            url = new URL("http://myworld.com/436789.xml");
            is = url.openStream(); // throws an IOException
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
            mue.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (is != null)
                    is.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                // nothing to see here
            }
        }

    }

}

class MyAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
    private static String username = "";
    private static String password = "";

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(MyAuthenticator.username, MyAuthenticator.password.toCharArray());
    }

    public static void setPasswordAuthentication(String username, String password) {
        MyAuthenticator.username = username;
        MyAuthenticator.password = password;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Hovan
could you please elaborate...